# changing the divs style using javascript explanation.

Tags: javascript

Hi sorry if this is a duplicate but I don't know what to search. The code below work without me doing document.getElementByID. Why is that? and is this faster or the same or slower then getting the element by id.

http://jsfiddle.net/eQXZa/

HTML

```
<div id="box1" style="background-color: #ff0000; width: 100px; height:100px;"></div>
```

JS

```
obj(box1);
function obj(object) 
{
    object.style.background = "#ccc";
}
```

Comment: Faster or slower, you shouldn't use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some browsers, elements are stored as globals by their ids so you can access them directly. To be safe, you shouldn't depend on this feature, and instead use `getElementById`.

Comment: it should be noted that "some browsers" means that you shouldn't rely on this

Comment: wow, do you know what I can search to read more about this? Not that I want to use it but just to read more about it. +1 thanks.